# How to delegate to call child component method and behave based on its value

Tags: reactjs

I have 3 components ***FormContainer***, ***UserNameInput*** and ***PasswordInput***. UserNameInput and PasswordInput has the method `validate` to validate its value and show the error message once it fails the validation. However, FormContainer submit button should also trigger these validations from the child components. I do not know what is a nice way to call it.

```
class FormContainer extends Component {
   handleSubmit = () => {
     //TODO delegate to UserNameInput and PasswordInput to validate
   }

   render() {
     <div>
        <UserNameInput .../> 
        <PasswordInput .../>
        <Button onClick={this.handleSubmit()}>
            Submit
        </Button>
     </div>

   }
}

class UserNameInput extends Component {
  validate = () => {
    const error = someValidation();
    if (error) {
      // Show the error message.
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  render() {
        ....
  }
}
```

One possible solution is to put validation logic into container and pass it down to **UserNameInput** and **PasswordInput**. I guess it is better that each input would have the validation logic rather than put it into the parent component.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If the validation is triggered by the form being submitted, then it actually makes more sense to put it into the parent (FormContainer). If the validation is 'on the fly' then it could equally reside in the parent or child components.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you go with this route "One possible solution is to put validation logic into container and pass it down to UserNameInput and PasswordInput" this is much better in my opinion because the validation logic would be decoupled with the presentation logic or if possible you could completely decouple all validation logic into its separate module and just import it in areas where you need it.